# What are the limits of "Unmovable"?

Tags: cypher-system

At Tier 3, the focus "Stands like a bastion" grant the ability "Unmovable" (p. 171):

> You avoid being knocked down, pushed back, or moved against your will
>   as long as you are upright and able to take actions. Enabler.

What if a character with such skill stands against a gigantic rolling boulder? Does she stops the boulder? What if she try to stop an hydraulic press with his body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unmovable, not Unkillable

The ability allows remaining in place so long as one is upright and able to take actions, but doesn't seem to help against being made un-action-able (such as by death). That implies that such a character will die before budging (e.g. from the damage done by a boulder's impact or the hydraulic press' crush).

Comment: A squishy character can be squished.